# Lisp Arithmetic simplification

Tags: lisp

I'm a newbie when it comes to programming in lisp and ill be honest recursion is not my forte, I was tasked with writing a function that would simplify arithmetic equations but not solve them. Here is the guidelines this is a school project by the way.

*Write function simplify that takes any arithmetic expression as described above (not just the examples shown) and returns a new function in which the following improvements are made, if they are possible:

1. Multiplication sub-expression 
   a. With a 0 as an argument, sub-expression is replaced by 0:  `(* 3 5 0) -> 0`
   b. With a 1 as an argument, the 1 is removed: `(* 1 2 6) -> (* 2 6)`.   If only one argument remains then the sub-expression is replaced by that argument:   `(* 1 6) -> 6`
2. Addition sub-expression
   a. Any occurrence of 0 is eliminated:  `(+ 0 2 7 7) -> (+ 2 7 7)`.  If only one argument remains, the sub-expression is eliminated:  `(+ 0 7) -> 7`

My group mates and I have written this so far :

```
(defun simplify (lis)
  (cond
   ((null lis) '())
   ((eq (car lis) '*)
    (cond
     ((not(null (member '0 lis))) 0)
     ((not(null (member '1 lis))) (simplify (remove '1 lis)))
     (t (simplify (cdr lis)))
     )
    )

   ((eq (car lis) '+)
    (cond
     (t 0)
     )
    )
   ((listp (car lis)) (cons (simplify (car lis))(simplify (cdr lis))))
   (t (cons (simplify (car lis)) (simplify (cdr lis))))

   )
  )
```

We cant get it to work Correctly if you have any suggestions! Thank you also you can ignore our + function that isn't finished.

Comment: In your `t` cases, you need to iterate over all the arguments, replacing them with the result of calling `simplify` on them. `mapcar` will be useful here.

Comment: could you explain a little further on what you mean by iterate over all the arguments

Comment: If you have `(* (+ 3 0) (* 1 10))`, you need to call `simplify` on `(+ 3 0)` and `(* 1 10)`, so that you get `(* 3 10)`.

Answer (score 1):

It's always good to try to keep functions as simple and short as possible. So let's break up this task into multiple steps:

For both `+` and `*` there is an identity element, that you are supposed to remove from the operation (as it doesn't affect the result).

```
(defun remove-identity-elements (operands identity)
  (flet ((is-identity (element)
           (equal element identity)))
    (let ((filtered-operands (remove-if #'is-identity operands)))
      (or filtered-operands (list identity)))))
```

This function returns a list of operands with identity elements removed. Note that I added a check to avoid returning an empty list, so if the `filtered-operands` are an empty list (`()`) the `or` will evaluate its second argument, returning a list with the identity element as single member.

For an operation, if it's called with only a single operand, you're supposed to simplify that to only the single operand. That task is a good candidate for another function:

```
(defun compact-single-operand-operation (expression)
  (let ((operands (rest expression)))
    (if (rest operands)
      expression
      (first operands))))
```

Handling an operation can then be done by first removing any identity elements from the operands and then eventually removing the operation all together:

```
(defun simplify-operation (operator operands identity)
  (compact-single-operand-operation
   (cons operator (remove-identity-elements operands identity))))
```

With these functions ready at hand we can approach the `simplify` function. First of all, we need to cover its recursive nature:

In order to simplify an operation, you need to first simplify each of its operands, as they could be complex (simplify-able) operations, too.

```
(defun simplify (expression)
  (if (listp expression)
      (let ((operator (first expression))
            (operands (mapcar #'simplify (rest expression))))
        ;; handle operations
        )
      expression))
```

I'm using `mapcar` with the currently being defined function `simplify` to get already simplified operands. To stop this recursion we need a base case: If the expression to simplify isn't a list, then we consider it as "self evaluating" and just return it unchanged (this is the "else" part of the `if`).

Handling the operations is done using the above function `simplify-operation`, though we need to add a special check to cope with a possible `0` in the operands of a multiplication:

```
(cond ((eq operator '+) (simplify-operation '+ operands 0))
      ((eq operator '*)
       (if (find 0 operands)
           0
           (simplify-operation '* operands 1)))
      (t (error "Unsupported operation")))
```

I also put together [a live example](http://ideone.com/LMLYJi) to play with.